# read email from office 365 in .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, mailkit

I want to read my Office 365 emails connected to my Azure account in a .net core environment. When I try to access my application on Azure and read my emails with the code below, it gives the "Authentication Failed" error. I will be giving you my permissions in the application below. Can you help me find out where the problem is?
Api Permissions:
**Microsoft Graph:** User.Read(Delegated), IMAP.AccessAsUser.All(Delegated)
**Office 365 Exchange Online:** IMAP.AccessAsApp(Application)

My Code:

```
public async Task<List<ReceivedEMails>> ReadEmailsAsync()
{
    var emailMessages = new List<ReceivedEMails>();

    try
    {
        // OAuth2 configuration
        var clientId = _configuration["EmailSettings:ClientId"];
        var tenantId = _configuration["EmailSettings:TenantId"];
        var clientSecret = _configuration["EmailSettings:ClientSecret"];
        var userEmail = _configuration["EmailSettings:EmailAddress"];
        var scope = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/.default" };

        // Get Access Token
        var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
            .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
            .WithAuthority(new Uri($"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/v2.0"))
            .Build();

        var result = await cca.AcquireTokenForClient(scope).ExecuteAsync();

        // Connect to IMAP server
        using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Imap.ImapClient())
        {
            await client.ConnectAsync("outlook.office365.com", 993, true);
            await client.AuthenticateAsync(new SaslMechanismOAuth2(userEmail, result.AccessToken)); //error:authentication failed.

            // Select inbox
            await client.Inbox.OpenAsync(FolderAccess.ReadOnly);

            var items = await client.Inbox.FetchAsync(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Full | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId);

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                var email = client.Inbox.GetMessage(item.UniqueId);

                emailMessages.Add(new ReceivedEMails
                {
                    EmailCode = email.MessageId,
                    EmailSubject = email.Subject,
                    EmailSender = email.From.Mailboxes.FirstOrDefault()?.Address,
                    EmailContent = email.TextBody,
                    CreatedDate = email.Date.DateTime
                });
            }

            await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Failed to read emails.", ex);
    }

    return emailMessages;
}
```

I want to read my emails in my outlook account in a .net core environment. The error I get is "Authenticated Failed"

Comment: You are using [O365 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations#get-a-message-collection) but not [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request) for listing messages. If you are willing to use graph api to query messages, you might take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75929261/14574199).

Comment: and just like you see, the outlook API in O365 API is DEPRECATED and is recommended to use Graph API instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Outlook Mail REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations) is DEPRECATED now and is recommended to migrating existing apps to use Microsoft Graph.

> As announced on November 17, 2020, version 2.0 of the Outlook REST API
> has been deprecated. The v2.0 REST endpoint will be fully
> decommissioned in November 2022, and the v2.0 documentation will be
> removed shortly afterwards. Migrate existing apps to use Microsoft
> Graph. See a comparison to start your migration.

When using Graph Api for listing message for a specific user, according to OP's code snippet `var scope = new string[] { "https://outlook.office.com/.default" };`, I'm afraid OP's trying to use Application API permission so that  we should at least having permission `Application: Mail.ReadBasic.All` and add admin consent.

[image]

Then we can use client credential flow + [Graph SDK for this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/mailfolder-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example) like below:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com";
var clientId = "aad_app_id";
var clientSecret = "client_secret";
var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
                tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var result = await graphClient.Users["{user-id}"].MailFolders["{mailFolder-id}"].Messages.GetAsync();
```